# Setting values to a form in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

can anyone help me, I'm making a CRUD in django and I want to set the form fields of the Edit section with the actual data of the item that I'm selecting. Can anyone tell me how can I do this.

forms.py

```
class editProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = ('object_id', 'slugp', 'category', 'add_date')
```

views.py

```
def product_update(request, object_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=object_id)
    category = product.category
    info_send = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = editProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            price = form.cleaned_data['price']
            stock = form.cleaned_data['stock']
            image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            manufacturer = form.cleaned_data['manufacturer']

            product.name = name
            product.description = description
            product.price = price
            product.stock = stock
            product.image = image
            product.manufacturer = manufacturer
            product.save()
            info = "Updated"
            info_send = True

        else:
            info = "ERROR updating"

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/catalog/'+category+'/product/')
    else:
        form = editProductForm()
        ctx = {'form':form}
        return render_to_response('dashboard/edit_product.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

edit_product.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% load bootstrap %}

{% block title %}Product {{product.name}}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        <h4>Here you can edit items</h4>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-container">
            <form id="edit_product_form" action="." method="POST" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|bootstrap }}
                <input id="btnSaveProduct" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save">
                <input class="btn btn-warning" type="reset" value="Clean">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks If someone can tell me how to set to the form fields the actual data of the item selected please help me!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you might be looking to display in your template:

```
<table>
    {% for field in form %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ field.label_tag }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ field.value }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

This will show, for all your fields, the current value of the field.

Answer (score 2):

You need the [`instance` option in the `ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm)

Couple of things:

- Use `get_object_or_404`
- Pass `instance=` into the initialization, and in `POST`: `editProductForm(instance=product)` and  `editProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=product)`
- Note the indentations of the `return` statements.
- Use `[]` instead of `.get()` while accessing keys from dictionaries.

Try this:

```
def product_update(request, object_id):

    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=object_id)
    category = product.category
    info_send = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = editProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=product)

        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            name = cd.get('name') #user get() instead of []
            description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            price = form.cleaned_data['price']
            stock = form.cleaned_data['stock']
            image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            manufacturer = form.cleaned_data['manufacturer']

            product.name = cd.get('name') #user get() instead of []
            product.description = description
            product.price = price
            product.stock = stock
            product.image = image
            product.manufacturer = manufacturer
            product.save()

            info = "Updated"
            info_send = True

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/catalog/'+category+'/product/')
        else:
            print form.errors
            info = "ERROR updating"

    else:
        form = editProductForm(instance=product)
        ctx = {'form':form}
    return render_to_response('dashboard/edit_product.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it worked just fine, when I use return HttpResponseRedirect('catalog/'+category.slugc+'/product/') my url gets this localhost:8000/catalog/product/1/catalog/snorkels/product/. And I need it localhost:8000/catalog/snorkels/product/ can you help me!

Comment: Yes.. I am not in a position to tell you where exactly, but definitely, looks like you forgot `/` at the beginning of where you want to redirect to `catalog/snorkels/product/`

Comment: Most of the lines inside the `is_valid()` block are unnecessary: you can just do `product = form.save()`, which automatically takes the values from `cleaned_data`.